# Share clipboard between different users on Mac

Tags: osx, keyboard-shortcuts, clipboard

Is there a program to allow me to share my clipboard between 2 accounts on my Mac (Snow-Leopard - 10.6.8)?

My only requirement is:

- Allows me to make a new keyboard shortcut like <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd> that will automatically copy the text to other accounts

I would *really* prefer it to be free, but a cheap program would do as well (under £5, like donationware...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A free suite is [Thinkbitz' CloudClip](http://www.thinkbitz.com/cloudclip/)(*).

I use it for years now and it works quite well. It comes with a keyboard  short cut and syncs between mutiple macs and iOS devices.

For the syncing it uses Apple's iCloud, which is sometimes slow (Strangely particularly when you sync over 3G) and not always reliable, but certainly good enough.

Note: CloudClip requires OSX Lion, so it might be time to upgrade! :-)

---

(*) Do not confuse it with Chimp Studios' CloudClip, which is *not* free.

Comment: +1 good program, but I can't upgrade to lion for iCloud. It runs too slow on my 4 year old Mac. In upgraded once before, but had to downgrade after a few weeks because it had basically rendered my Mac useless

Comment: I got a new Mac - using this now :)